I am Stuck on CS50 Finance, on the /buy function i guess. started from scratch again but no luck :(
So the whole thing basically works - i can Register a new user, i can login i can get the shares quotes etc.
But as soon as i try to buy a share, i get an error: ValueError: NOT NULL constraint failed: portfolio.shares.
CODE:
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""

    # if request method is GET, display buy.html form
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("buy.html")

    # if request method is POST
    else:
        # save stock symbol, number of shares, and quote dict from form
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
        shares = request.form.get("shares")
        quote = lookup(symbol)

        # return apology if symbol not provided or invalid
        if quote == None:
            return apology("must provide valid stock symbol", 400)

        # return apology if shares not provided or invalid
        if not shares or not shares.isdigit() or int(shares) <= 0:
            return apology("must provide a positive number of shares", 400)

        # cast symbol to uppercase and cast shares to int, in order to work with them
        symbol = symbol.upper()
        shares = int(shares)
        purchase = quote['price'] * shares

        # make sure user can afford current stock, checking amount of cash in users table

        # select this user's cash balance from users table
        balance = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :id", id=session["user_id"])
        balance = balance[0]['cash']
        remainder = balance - purchase

        # if purchase price exceeds balance, return error
        if remainder < 0:
            return apology("insufficient funds", 400)

        # query portfolio table for row with this userid and stock symbol:
        row = db.execute("SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE userid = :id AND symbol = :symbol",
                         id=session["user_id"], symbol=symbol)

        # if row doesn't exist yet, create it but don't update shares
        if len(row) != 1:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO portfolio (userid, symbol) VALUES (:id, :symbol)",
                       id=session["user_id"], symbol=symbol)

        # get previous number of shares owned
        oldshares = db.execute("SELECT shares FROM portfolio WHERE userid = :id AND symbol = :symbol",
                               id=session["user_id"], symbol=symbol)
        oldshares = oldshares[0]["shares"]

        # add purchased shares to previous share number
        newshares = oldshares + shares

        # update shares in portfolio table
        db.execute("UPDATE portfolio SET shares = :newshares WHERE userid = :id AND symbol = :symbol",
                   newshares=newshares, id=session["user_id"], symbol=symbol)

        # update cash balance in users table
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = :remainder WHERE id = :id",
                   remainder=remainder, id=session["user_id"])

        # update history table
        db.execute("INSERT INTO history (userid, symbol, shares, method, price) VALUES (:userid, :symbol, :shares, 'Buy', :price)",
                   userid=session["user_id"], symbol=symbol, shares=shares, price=quote['price'])

    # redirect to index page
    return redirect("/")

HTML:
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Buy
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/buy" method="post">
        <div style="width:30%; margin: auto; class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="symbol" placeholder="Symbol" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input style="width:30%; margin: auto; class="form-control" name="shares" placeholder="Shares" type="number" min="0">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Buy</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}

.db
CREATE TABLE portfolio (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    userid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    symbol TEXT NOT NULL,
    shares INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users(id)
);
CREATE TABLE history (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    userid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    symbol TEXT NOT NULL,
    shares INTEGER NOT NULL,
    price REAL NOT NULL,
    timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users(id)
);

I googled, i asked my LLM, i searched in different forums, stackoverflow, reddit, ytb etc.
Along the way i was able to fix some earlier Problems but sadly on the check50 i still get this:
**:( buy handles valid purchase
    application raised an exception (see the log for more details)**
log:
sending GET request to /signin
sending POST request to /login
sending POST request to /buy
exception raised in application: ValueError: NOT NULL constraint failed: portfolio.shares

Please tell me if you need aditional information, i am thankfull for every input/help i get, i im stuck with this since over a week now :)
BG

Are you sure shares isn't null?

INSERT INTO portfolio (userid, symbol) VALUES (:id, :symbol) You didn't provide the number of shares when creating the new row. And there's no default value specified in the table definition. So it uses NULL by default, and then gets an error because the column is declared NOT NULL

So either specify a default value when creating the table, or provide an initial number of shares when inserting the row.

Yes! After specifying a default value on the table(i used 0) it really worked!
Thanks alot!!
